# Concat is not working in mysql inclause

Tags: mysql, concatenation, in-clause

Please help me, i try to fetch category list as like below, where category ids is passed in inclause, it returns two rows.

```
mysql> select c_id,c_name from category where c_id in (870,854);
+------+---------------+
| c_id | c_name        |
+------+---------------+
|  854 | Telugu        |
|  870 | Telugu Events |
+------+---------------+
```

Whereas same category id is concatenated and passed to inclause as parameter, but its returning only one row insted of two rows.

```
mysql> select c_id,c_name from category where c_id in (select concat(870,',',854) as c_id);
+------+---------------+
| c_id | c_name        |
+------+---------------+
|  870 | Telugu Events |
+------+---------------+
```

Please clarify me.

Thanks.

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which CONCAT (or GROUP_CONCAT) is the solution. If you find yourself using these functions, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to use `concat` in the `in-clause`, this is needed when you have some dynamic data, and for this you need to use dynamic query using `prepare`

Here how it is done

```
set @c_id := concat(870,',',854);
set @qry = concat("select * from category where c_id in (",@c_id,")");

prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23357/2)**

Comment: Hi, actually i modified the query for easier understanding, below is the exact query, where category id input will come like ''-854-870-'', so im using string replace function to convert to 854,870 to pass it in mysql in clause, but its not returning two result rows. select c_id,c_name from category where c_id in (select REPLACE(trim('-' from '-854-870-'),'-',','));

Comment: You should be using application level for such replacements and then pass them into the query.

Comment: Ya sure, your suggestion is correct, but i am eager to know why this is not working in query.

Comment: The moment you pass some value as string inside the `IN` clause it will be treated as string and mysql will get the result for the first record. Thats why you need dynamic sql using `concat` like I have shown in the answer. So that the entire query is in a variable and then execute the query in that variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

```
SELECT c_id, c_name 
FROM category 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c_id, (SELECT CONCAT(870,',',854) AS c_id))
```

Thanks.